# Why when I do a LEFT JOIN in MySQL does it not reduce the number of rows lookups?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
SUM(IF(r.rating_rating <= 5 AND r.rating_rating >= 4, 1, 0)),
SUM(IF(r.rating_rating <= 4 AND r.rating_rating >= 3, 1, 0)),
SUM(IF(r.rating_rating <= 3 AND r.rating_rating >= 0, 1, 0))
FROM management amp
LEFT JOIN wp_posts p ON  amp.post_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_ratings r  ON amp.post_id  = r.rating_postid
AND amp.editor_id = 2
```

When I use the EXPLAIN method I get this:

[image]

Should the last row in the EXPLAIN result get the same number as the first row (1056)?

Why is it looking up 14 767 rows? Is there a way to bring it down to 1056?

Comment: Rather than a picture of the EXPLAIN, can you just post the EXPLAIN, as well as SHOW CREATE statements for all relevant tables. FWIW. I prefer to the use "\G" delimiter for EXPLAINs (instead of ";")

Comment: How is the system supposed to know which rows in r match? The answer it is does not. Therefore it needs to read the full table to check which rows match your join rule.

You could possibly optimize this by defining an appropriate index on r. As it seems there is no (helpful) index defined.

Comment: How many rows do you have in the table `r`?  It's going to have to check them all against your table `amp`.  One row in `amp` could conceivably match any number of rows in `r` *(because there is nothing to stop many rows in `r` having the same value of `rating_postid` as each other)*.  Maybe you could create indexes and foreign key constraints to provide the optimisation engine with more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A LEFT JOIN without an index will read through all the rows in the second table and move matching rows into a cache (the "[join buffer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html)" you see there) before presenting the data.

The only way to remove it is add an index on rating_postid to wp_ratings as it can then use the index to just seek the rows it needs. NB: It will still pull more than 1,056 rows if there are more than 1 rating per post.